# How to make decimal places include in the operation

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have problem here about my javascript.
This javascript works well, but the problem is the operation that its run did not include the decimal places that user input.
For example the user put 13.2-10. The answer should be 3.2 rite. But the output result is 3.
It do not calculate the decimal places. So if there someone may help, that would really be appreciate. This are my javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function calcSubMTotal(p) {
        var minus = 0;
        var isFirst=true;
        var minus_total = $('#' + p + '');

        $('.' + p + '').each(function (i) {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
                if(!isFirst)
                    minus -= parseInt(this.value); 
                else
                {
                    minus=parseInt(this.value);
                    isFirst=false;
                }
            }
        });

        minus_total.val(minus);
    }

    $('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function () {
        calcSubMTotal("rr");
    });
});
```

Comment: You should Use parseFloat instead of parseInt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `parseInt` which will return integers. Use `parseFloat` instead.

Note that this will lead some some (possibly) unexpected results, since in JavaScript:

```
13.2 - 10 == 3.1999999999999993
```

This is actually correct, so when you're displaying it, you probably want to do something like:

```
minus_total.val(minus.toFixed(2));
```

Since:

```
(13.2 - 10).toFixed(2) == "3.20"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But may i know how to get the result be in 2 significant figure?

Comment: Ah, already added a note about that :). Did you mean *signification figure* or *decimal places*?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to give significant figures so you'd need to create that yourself, basically by counting digits from the left of the string and zeroing non-significant figures and removing non-significant decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Integers do not have decimals places, try     parseFloat()     instead of     parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

You should  Use parseFloat instead of parseInt .